# WooCommerce Currency Symbol

Tags: woocommerce, currency, symbols

I am recently working with WooCommerce WordPress project for my client and I am editing a plugin for WooCommerce WordPress. I am trying to display the product price to include the currency code use this function

```
 * @param mixed $item
 * @param bool $inc_tax (default: false).
 * @param bool $round (default: true).
 * @return float
 */
public function get_item_total( $item, $inc_tax = false, $round = true ) {

    $qty = ( ! empty( $item['qty'] ) ) ? $item['qty'] : 1;

    if ( $inc_tax ) {
        $price = ( $item['line_total'] + $item['line_tax'] ) / max( 1, $qty );
    } else {
        $price = $item['line_total'] / max( 1, $qty );
    }

    $price = '<span class="price">' . $round ? round( $price, wc_get_price_decimals() ) . '</span>' : '<span class="price">' . $price . '</span>' ;

    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_amount_item_total',  $price, $this, $item, $inc_tax, $round ); 
}
```

But it spits out a number like 55 with out the currency symbol.  is there anyway get the number with currency symbol like $55 ?

Thank you for all your help

Comment: did you tried preppending the currency using "get_woocommerce_currency()" ? because in your code ther´s nothing to echo that.

For example here: $price = '<span class="price">' . get_woocommerce_currency() .........

Answer (score 1):

ty rgdesign

This was the fix  it works now

```
public function get_item_total( $item, $inc_tax = false, $round = true ) {

    $qty = ( ! empty( $item['qty'] ) ) ? $item['qty'] : 1;

    if ( $inc_tax ) {
        $price = ( $item['line_total'] + $item['line_tax'] ) / max( 1, $qty );
    } else {
        $price = $item['line_total'] / max( 1, $qty );
    }

   $currency_symbol = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();

   $price = $round ? round($price, wc_get_price_decimals() ): $price;

$price = '<span class="price">' .$currency_symbol . $price .'</span>';  
    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_amount_item_total',$price, $this, $item, $inc_tax, $round ); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it to be very easy.  Just insert the following code block to **functions.php** file under theme folder.

```
//Change the symbol of an existing currency
add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'change_existing_currency_symbol', 10, 2);
     switch( $currency ) {
          case 'USD': $currency_symbol = 'USD&#36;'; break;
}
     return $currency_symbol;
}
```