# how to add currency symbol suffix in woocommerce without using switch case

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

The issue is that there are so many currencies and i don't want to write switch cases for each.
Is there any walk-around from this.

**What I tried**

Saw this link:- [WooCommerce Currency Symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41901765/woocommerce-currency-symbol), https://www.codemyownroad.com/add-currency-code-suffix-prices-woocommerce, https://www.speakinginbytes.com/2014/04/currency-code-symbol-woocommerce

**My Code**

```
function addPriceSuffix($format, $currency_pos) {
    switch ( $currency_pos ) {
        case 'left' :
            $currency = get_woocommerce_currency();
            $format = '%1$s%2$s&nbsp;' . $currency;
        break;
    }

    return $format;
}

add_action('woocommerce_price_format', 'addPriceSuffix', 1, 2);
```

But my problem didn't solve. Any plugin or any functionality that could help me with this.Thanks.

Comment: Why would you need a switch case for all of them? You need a method that takes the price, the symbol and the position. The only decision is then prefix, suffix or without symbol.